# Scrollable table with fixed header

Tags: html-table, scrollable

I searched for some solutions in PHP/HTML/CSS for this, but nothing worked so far, maybe because in most of those examples were sooo much of code so I got lost in it. Could someone explain to me what I need to do or put some simple sample code here?

Comment: PHP, sorry.. or maybe HTML/CSS could be enough :)

Comment: I tried this http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html# but I totally don´t get it, there´s no explanation, I don´t know what part of code does what I need. I tried to implement those css blocks to my code but it only totally broke the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code (taken from the link in your comment) is the basic code you need. Next time you need to figure that kind of thing out, just remove segments of code to see what breaks, and leave out everything that doesn't break something that you need.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.tableContainer {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #963;
    height: 285px; /* html>body tbody.scrollContent height plus 23px for the header */
    overflow: auto;
    width: 756px /* Remember to leave 16px for the scrollbar! */
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent {
    display: block;
    height: 262px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%
}


html>body thead.fixedHeader tr {
    display: block
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th { /* TH 1 */
    width: 200px
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th + th { /* TH 2 */
    width: 240px
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th + th + th { /* TH 3 +16px for scrollbar */
    width: 316px
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent td { /* TD 1 */
    width: 200px
}

html>body thead.scrollContent td + td { /* TD 2 */
    width: 240px
}

html>body thead.scrollContent td + td + td { /* TD 3 +16px for scrollbar */
    width: 316px
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="scrollTable">
    <thead class="fixedHeader">
        <tr class="alternateRow">
            <th><a href="#">Header 1</a></th>
            <th><a href="#">Header 2</a></th>
            <th><a href="#">Header 3</a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="scrollContent">
        <tr class="normalRow">
            <td>Cell Content 1</td>
            <td>Cell Content 2</td>
            <td>Cell Content 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alternateRow">
            <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
            <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
            <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
        </tr>
        .........
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent so much time with this with no result :) This way it´s much easier to understand the code :)

Comment: No worries, I had the same problems as well when learning HTML/CSS/JS a few years ago, and am still having them with other languages... The more you do it, the easier it becomes.

Answer (score 2):

## Table fixed header using CSS

The simplest would be to `position: sticky;` your `th` elements:

```css
.tableFix { /* Scrollable parent element */
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.tableFix table{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tableFix th,
.tableFix td{
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

.tableFix thead th {
  position: sticky;  /* Edge, Chrome, FF */
  top: 0px;
  background: #fff;  /* Some background is needed */
}
```

```html
<div class="tableFix">

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>H1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th><th>4</th><th>5th Header</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>R1C2</td><td>R1C2</td><td>R1C3</td><td>R1C4</td><td>R1C5</td></tr>
      <tr><td>R2C1</td><td>R2C2</td><td>R2C3</td><td>R2C4</td><td>R2C5</td></tr>
      <tr><td>R3C1</td><td>R3C2</td><td>R3C3</td><td>R3C4</td><td>R3C5</td></tr>
      <tr><td>R4C1</td><td>R4C2</td><td>R4C3</td><td>R4C4</td><td>R4C5</td></tr>
      <tr><td>R5C1</td><td>R5C2</td><td>R5C3</td><td>R5C4</td><td>R5C5</td></tr>
      <tr><td>R6C1</td><td>R6C2</td><td>R6C3</td><td>R6C4</td><td>R6C5</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

## Table fixed header for older browsers

If the **browsers you need to support** do not encompass the position's `sticky` value,  you can take a look at **[Fix table head using a bit of Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47923622/383904)**