# Make Bootstrap table scrollable without effecting the grid system

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

How can I make a table scrollable without effecting the grid system?
 How can I make table scrollable without disturbing the col-xs tag?

```
 <table class="col-xs-12">  
    <thead>
                            <th class="col-xs-2">A</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-1">B</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-1">c</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-2">d</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-2">e</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-1">f</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-1">g</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-1">h</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-1">i</th>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control""></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                              </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the  table need to be scrollable on all screen sizes?

If you just need it to scroll on small devices you can use bootstrap's `.table-responsive` class

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Comment: it should be scrollable when tbody has more than 3 rows :)

Comment: @user3782454 Ah, I thought you wanted horizontal scroll rather than vertical. For vertical scroll take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to wrap a table inside the div with class `table-responsive` and changing `col-xs-12` to `table` or at worst `row`?. I haven't been using Bootstrap for a while so sorry if I am wrong.

If you think about vertical scroll then, well, maybe fixed height for the table container (let it be `div`) and `overflow: scroll`?