# CSS, Header-Absolute, scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need that  (table headers) would be on top and then I scroll down through
 the list, that headers stay in place(at the top of the page) not in the left.
I tried to edit CSS, but maybe its HTML fault?
HTML

```
    <div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Header A</th>
          <td>col 1 - A</td>
          <td>col 2 - A (WITH LONGER CONTENT)</td>
          <td>col 3 - A</td>
          <td>col 4 - A</td>
          <td>col 5 - A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Header B</th>
          <td>col 1 - B</td>
          <td>col 2 - B</td>
          <td>col 3 - B</td>
          <td>col 4 - B</td>
          <td>col 5 - B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Header C</th>
          <td>col 1 - C</td>
          <td>col 2 - C</td>
          <td>col 3 - C</td>
          <td>col 4 - C</td>
          <td>col 5 - C</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed; 
  width: 100%;
  *margin-left: -100px;/*ie7*/
}
td, th {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding:10px;
  width:100px;
}
th {
  position:absolute;
  *position: relative; /*ie7*/
  left:0; 
  width:100px;
}
.outer {position:relative}
.inner {
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:visible;
  width:400px; 
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

Comment: Check this link for Your answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/5PFak/71/

```
change some layout of your table.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's more of a CSS issue although I'm not sure you've written your HTML the proper way either.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap) should help you solve your problem.

Tell me if it doesn't but I'm sure you'll find an answer by trying "fixed headers table" at google anyway.