# How to make header static while scrolling on page

Tags: html

I am trying to figure out where would be the best place to insert the position: fiuxed code into my below code. I am trying to make the content stay on the top of the page when scrolling? THanks!

[_table width="100%">[_tr>[_td width="50%" style="text-align:left" valign="bottom">[*i*]Over the [*u*][*b*]past week[*/b*][*/u*][*/td*][_td width="40%" colspan="3">[_table width="100%">[_tr>[*td width="25%" style="text-align:center" valign="bottom">Never[*/td_]
[*td width="25%" style="text-align:center" valign="bottom">Once[*/td_]
[*td width="25%" style="text-align:center" valign="bottom">A few times[*/td_]
[*td width="25%" style="text-align:center" valign="bottom">Everyday[*/td_][*/tr*][*/table*][*/td*][_td width="10%" style="text-align:center" valign="bottom">Tick this box if distressing

Comment: Your code is difficult to read or understand.  I recommend taking a read through this page [regarding how to cleanly format code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2):

[This is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap)

Anyway, online you can find a lot of plugins and tutorials about this task:

[Pure CSS Scrollable Table with Fixed Header](http://anaturb.net/csstips/sheader.htm)

[Creating Cross Browser Scrollable](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/11/10/creating-cross-browser-scrollable-tbody)