# How to implement fixed header for table in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I tried a lot to freeze the header of a table in bootstrap but was not able to find any solution. I tried the code samples from the internet but the design of my table is getting messed up.
My code follows below:

**HTML**

```
<div id="user_list" class="table-responsive">
   <asp:GridView ID="grdUsersList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-hover" HeaderStyle-CssClass="info" BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="Horizontal" Width="100%">
   </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

**CSS for above div**

```
#user_list {
    overflow:auto;
    border: 1px solid #337AB7;
    max-height: 500px;
}

#user_list table {
    border-color: #337AB7;
}

#user_list table th {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Now, finally populating grid dynamically using jquery**

```
$('#ChildContent_grdUsersList').append('<thead></thead>');
$('#ChildContent_grdUsersList thead').append('<tr><th class="info" style="width: 3%;"></th>\
        <th class="info" style="width: 12%;">Name</th>\
        <th class="info" style="width: 15%;">Login ID</th>\
        <th class="info" style="width: 15%;">Email ID</th>\
        <th class="info" style="width: 10%;">Phone No.</th>\
        <th class="info" style="width: 13%;">Designation</th>\
        <th class="info" style="width: 12%;">Reporting To</th>\
        <th class="info" style="width: 10%;">Business</th>\
        <th class="info" style="width: 10%;">User Type</th></tr>');

$.each(response, function (index, itemData) {
    $('#ChildContent_grdUsersList').append('<tr><td class="text-left"><input type="radio" id="radio_' + itemData.UserID + '" name="user" class="radio" value="' + itemData.UserID + '" onchange="showVal(this);"></input></td>\
        <td class="text-left">' + itemData.UserName + '</td>\
        <td class="text-left">' + itemData.LoginId + '</td>\
        <td class="text-left">' + itemData.EmailId + '</td>\
        <td class="text-left">' + itemData.Phone + '</td>\
        <td class="text-left">' + itemData.Designation + '</td>\
        <td class="text-left">' + itemData.ReportingTo + '</td>\
        <td class="text-left">' + itemData.BusinessAssigned + '</td>\
        <td class="text-left">' + itemData.UserType + '</td></tr>');
});
```

I want to freeze the header of the above table. On applying `display:block;` to `<thead>` and `<tbody>`, the whole design is getting messed up.
I even tried applying "*sticky headers*", "*freeze headers*" kind of plugins but still the headers are not getting fixed.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: try tableScroll plugin

Comment: I do not want to use jquery UI and I think tableScroll is part of jquery UI

Comment: Its not depending on jquery UI. have a look at this [link](http://table-scroll.site90.com/)

Comment: But, in that link I saw that data is not moving up and down while scrolling. When I am leaving mouse click then the data is appearing. But, this should not happen, isn't it? while scrolling, data should move up and down.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following answer wich was solved on 2014: [Scrollable table with fixed header in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap)

If it does not fit your needs, let me know.

Comment: I tried this before but as I said that on applying "display : block" in thead and tbody section, the whole design is getting messed up. Can you tell me how to post image then I can post some screenshots which might help you to understand better that what exactly is happening on applying the css in thead and tbody

Comment: I cannot understand why the width is getting messed up as I set tbody and thead as block