# jQuery - Loop Through TD widths and then Loop through TH and apply TD widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fluid table that now needs a fixed thead.  The issue being when you make the thead fixed the th-s don't respect the width of the tbody's td-s.  The sizing of the columns are all handled with BootStrap.  I have read quite a bit on this subject and seen two solutions.  For argument's sake both will not work for me.

1. Lock down widths on the table, th, and tds.  So no responsive widths - hence horizontal scrolling.
2. Use jquery to find the `window width` and return the `height` to the table. Then do a inner table scroll with a locked header. (example of found solution http://www.bootply.com/JnOYtO9xzn#)

What I would like to try is find the `width` on all the `td` and pass those `width` to the corresponding `th` (if I need to apply classes like th1, td1 so be it).  Essentially I am trying to binding the td widths to the th. Also, on `window width` change update.

Table example: http://jsfiddle.net/u2xZU/165/ or https://jsfiddle.net/5hozvm5d/4/

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to work with selectors to get elements with jQuery? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will ensure that the `th`s in `thead` always equal the widths of the `td`s in their column:

```
var timer;
$(window).resize(function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer= setTimeout(function() {
    $('.table tbody tr:first td').each(function(idx) {  //get the first row of tds
      $('.table thead tr:first th').eq(idx)
        .width($(this).width());                        //set corresponding th width
    });
  },10);
}).resize();
```

Using `setTimeout()` prevents the function from running constantly as the window is resized.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/so9tLd9d/2)

Comment: Is there a way to have the function fire on load and then after on window resize?  It doesn't work until I resize the window.

Comment: Yes, just call `resize()` immediately after defining the method.  Sorry, I should have included that in my original post.  Now updated.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty complicated.  You might consider using the DataTable plug-in referenced here
[Scrollable table with fixed header in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap)