# Issues with Locked Header CSS

Tags: css

I have some tables in my HelpDesk software that I wanted to lock the headers.  I found this:
[Scrollable table with fixed header in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap/)

I have edited the CSS and HTML and it's working where the header does lock in to place. However, I have 2 issues that I can't figure out. First, the header row will not span the complete width of the table. Second, the final column which is a note column, I want to make larger than the rest of the columns. Here is my CSS:

```
.formatTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color:lightgray
}
.hoverTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ffff99;
  cursor:pointer;
}
/*.hoverTable tr:first-child:hover {
background-color: #0c268d;
cursor:default;
}*/
.formatTable tr:first-child {
  background-color: #0c268d;
  font-weight: normal;
  color:white;
}
th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
@media screen and (min-width:361px)
{
  table.TicketLists {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .TicketLists thead, tbody, tr, td, th { 
    display: block;
  }
  .TicketLists tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
  }
  .TicketLists tbody {
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .TicketLists tbody td {
    width: 12.2%;
    float: left;
  }
  .TicketLists th {
    float: left;
  }
  .notesColumn {
    width: 22%;
  }
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle for the code: [Header Locking not working fully](https://jsfiddle.net/t4zwsrdw/)

and here is a picture of what it currently looks like:

[image]

As you can see in the CSS, I have tried to create one column which is wider (called `.notesColumn`) and it has not done anything.

Comment: a jsfiddle would be easier to understand for us

Comment: @dr_debug, I just added a jsfiddle to the question.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at:

https://jsfiddle.net/t4zwsrdw/10/

your the th needs a width, because it's display block and floating.

```
   .TicketLists th {
    float: left;
    width: 12.2%;
    text-align:left;
}
```

#### UPDATE

```
.notesColumn {
    width: 49.8% !important;
}
```

Make your `.noteColumn` wider and add the class to the last th:

```
<th class="notesColumn">
        Opening Note
</th>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t4zwsrdw/12/

this version has the header above the whole table.

Comment: Thank you dr_debug.  That partially fixed the issue.  The heading now covers more of the table but it still does not go over the whole table.