# Fixed header for dynamically generated ng-table

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have created a ng-table with dynamic header and body with sorting. The table is quite long so I want it to have fixed header with scrolling body. I even tried the `cornflourblue-angu-fixed-header-table`. It worked but created another problem that is the header and the corresponding column width is not matching. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Please share the relevant code in an easy-to-read format. Its impossible to suggest a solution when we don't even know what you are doing.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap