# HTML table with fixed header and footer and scrollable body without fixed widths

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I want to to create a table with fixed `thead` and `tfoot` and a scrollable `tbody`!

I've tried several approaches, both CSS only and CSS + Javascript, but they are all weak and unreliable and I can easily *break* them by changing the markup in the demo.

What I want is a way to have the table to **behave like a table**, this means that the browser will **automatically adjust columns** based on the content (both at page load that in case of window resize) and that in these scenarios:

1. if the content of the column's header (`thead > tr > th`) is larger than the content of the column's body (`tbody > tr > td`) and larger than the content of the column's footer (`tfoot > tr > td`) the column should resize based on the size of the column's header
2. if the content of the column's body (`tbody > tr > td`) is larger than the content of the column's header (`thead > tr > th`) and larger than the content of the column's footer (`tfoot > tr > td`) the column should resize based on the size of the column's body
3. if the content of the column's footer (`tfoot > tr > td`) is larger than the content of the column's header (`thead > tr > th`) and larger than the content of the column's body (`tbody > tr > td`) the column should resize based on the size of the column's footer

The `table` below should clarify the scenarios:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header one *leads the width* (case 1)</th>
      <th>Header two</th>
      <th>Header three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Footer one</td>
      <td>Footer two</td>
      <td>Footer three *leads the width* (case 3)</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

I want a clean (as possible) and reliable solution that will work for the different scenarios, possibly CSS only but also JavaScript is OK (vanilla and clean JavaScript, not jQuery plugins).
I don't care about old browser support (it would be great to have it or at least to reach a solution which can degrade gracefully on old browser but it's optional)... I can even accept to use `div`s instead of table nodes if the final solution works as expected... so in 2016, with modern browser and CSS is this possible somehow?!

**EDIT:**

The body should scroll vertically and the table may have any number of columns

Comment: Can u use datatables??

Comment: you want to achieve the vertical or horizontal scrolling?

Comment: Vertical scrolling

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap#23518981) answer?

Comment: I liked this one: https://codepen.io/w3core/pen/KzNjeo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally implemented a working solution!

The relevant CSS is the following:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #efefef;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
  border-top: 41px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 41px solid transparent;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td + td {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

td, th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 10px;
}

thead tr th,
tfoot tr td {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

thead tr th div,
tfoot tr td div {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

thead tr th div {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

tfoot tr td div {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

tfoot tr td div.c1,
thead tr th div.c1 {
  background: violet;
}

tfoot tr td div.c2,
thead tr th div.c2 {
  background: green;
}

tfoot tr td div.c3,
thead tr th div.c3 {
  background: yellow;
}

thead tr th div {
  top: 0;
}

tfoot tr td div {
  bottom: 0;
}

thead tr th:first-child div,
tfoot tr td:first-child div {
  border-left: none;
}
```

And this is the markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Header one *leads the width* (case 1)
            <div class="c1">
              Header one *leads the width* (case 1)
            </div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Header two
            <div class="c2">
              Header two
            </div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Header three
            <div class="c3">
              Header three
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three [first]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column one</td>
          <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
          <td>Column three [LATEST]</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Footer one
            <div class="c1">
              Footer one
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            Footer two
            <div class="c2">Footer two</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            Footer three *leads the width* (case 3)
            <div class="c3">Footer three *leads the width* (case 3)</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE11 (I don't know how it behaves on older browsers). 
See it on codepen: https://codepen.io/daveoncode/pen/LNomBE

Comment: Breaks if you make the window narrower than the table content. Although, this can be handled in most cases with a min-width.

Comment: Also only supports `text-align:left` for the header. The div's in the header use 100% width of the entire table instead of the th cell.

Comment: Neat and easy CSS solution, that's only missing the horizontal scrolling. Horizontal scrolling of header & footer might be possible to achieve using javascript.

Comment: Well, @daveoncode you should ask if it would work on older mozillas and alike because `overflow-y` was invented by IE and will be compatible way back to IE's of 1997 or of the first Standards complian browser on the market.

Comment: Only works if table is smaller than page-width.  Otherwise, when you x-scroll the content the 'fake' headers created (which are fixed) do not move with the content.

Answer (score 5):

**HTML table with fixed header and footer and scrollable body without fixed widths using CSS only**.
This is simple logic we can use table header put **position: sticky** method below the example:

```
table th {
position:sticky;
top: 0;
}
```

Comment: The cells of the footer need an additional anchor to the bottom: `bottom: 0;`

Answer (score 4):

#### UPDATE 2022

Nowadays and for awhile browsers have full support for `position: sticky`

So we can apply it to `thead th` and `tfoot tr`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

table {
  width: 100%
}

thead th,
tfoot tr {
  position: sticky;
  background: red
}

thead th {
  top: 0
}

tfoot tr {
  bottom: 0
}

th,
td {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center
}


/*give some space between thead and tfoot*/

tbody tr:first-of-type td {
  padding-top:  10px;
}

tbody tr:last-of-type td {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header one *leads the width* (case 1)</th>
      <th>Header two</th>
      <th>Header three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column one</td>
      <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
      <td>Column three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Footer one</td>
      <td>Footer two</td>
      <td>Footer three *leads the width* (case 3)</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

#### OLD Answer

you can achieve what you want by using a wrapper to your table (`div`) and make the `tr` from `thead` and `tfoot` a `position:absolute`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

div {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%
}

thead tr,
tfoot tr {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 15px;
  /* to not cover the scrollbar*/
  background: red
}

thead th,
tfoot td {
  display: inline-block;
}

thead tr {
  top: 0
}

tfoot tr {
  top: 500px/* same value has max-height from div */
}

th,
td {
  width: calc((100%/3) - 5px);
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center
}


/*give some space between thead and tfoot*/

tbody tr:first-of-type td {
  padding-top: 35px;
}

tbody tr:last-of-type td {
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header one *leads the width* (case 1)</th>
        <th>Header two</th>
        <th>Header three</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column one</td>
        <td>Column two *leads the width* (case 2)</td>
        <td>Column three</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>Footer one</td>
        <td>Footer two</td>
        <td>Footer three *leads the width* (case 3)</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example does not work, see here: http://codepen.io/daveoncode/pen/VaOWgO?editors=1100#anon-login moreover you are assigning width to tds (33%), but the approach should works always (even for table with 4, 10, 50 columns)

Comment: I'm able to scroll just the `tbody` through the `div` and if you have more than 3 columns, just do the math, 100/3 =33.3%, so for 4 columns change to 25%, 100/4=25%

Comment: the scrolling part is easy, the problem is the column alignment and in your example is not working... moreover, by using a table, the browser is usually smart enough to adjust column size based on content, this means I can have a column of 60% and two of 20%, is not a simple math division ;)

Comment: if you want to even columns then it is simple math ;), but what you looking for is something like the `width:auto`

Answer (score -14):

```
$.ajax({
          url: "upload.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: fd,
          processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
          contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        }).done(function( data ) {
            console.log("PHP Output:");
            console.log( data );
        });
        return false;
    }
```