# Scrollable table with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning angularjs with bootstrap, I am displaying data in table now it has many columns and hence data overflows and can be seen by scrolling the page to right, but this means that complete page needs to scrolled i need only the table component to be scrollable instead of the complete page. How can i achieve that ?

i have given overflow-x as scroll but still the complete page is scrolled instead of just table

```
table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped" style="overflow-x: scroll">
```

Comment: Just try overflow-x:auto;

Comment: You can have a div around the table with fix width and having overflow-x as scroll/auto.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrollable table with fixed header in bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define style in table property like this:

style="overflow-x: auto; width:200px;
    height: 389px;"

Answer (score 1):

Set a size for the table (e.g. use 100vh for full page-height), then apply

overflow: scroll;

to your table, and the element should scroll independently.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another div around your table with class of `table-responsive`.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <div class="table table-striped">
    Your table
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Responsive tables**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)