# How to fix the bootstrap-table header?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, fixed-header-tables

I've data inside a bootstrap table. As the rows increases, the header will be out of sight on vertical scroll. So I need to fix the header of the bootstrap table with table body vertical scrollable. Also,the horizontal scroll for the whole table when columns exceed in the page.

[Reference implementation without bootstrap](http://joshondesign.com/p/projects/css-tables-demo/test1.html).This is implemented by using two tables. One for header and the other for body.

I've the following data which is similar to my original data.

*NOTE*:I am not using any `col-*-*` for `table`'s `td`. Because my header columns are more than 12. And may increase up to 15. So I don't use the column classes.

**HTML**

```
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;">
          ABCD
        </th>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;">
          Asadh uysdsgh
        </th>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;">
          ghdsgsh sdfsdjsd
        </th>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;">
          sdagfh sdhfsjk
        </th>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;">
          sdhfasgh sdjkj
        </th>
        <th style="display: none; cursor: pointer;">
          shadfj sjdskdl
        </th>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;">
          sddgjgfhgshdf skldj
        </th>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;">
          sdfsffsd sdfsd
        </th>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;">
          sdfsd sdfsd
        </th>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;">
          fhgdd sdg sfs fsfsffsd sdfffs
        </th>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;">
          fsdfsd dvf ffff
        </th>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;">
          fsdfsd dvf ffff
        </th>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;">
          sfgasad sdfjhjshj
        </th>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          579852
        </td>
        <td>
          21June_The hhjhj bhjhhkj
        </td>
        <td>
          US jhgg
        </td>
        <td>
          sdafss
        </td>
        <td>
          sdfsdfssd
        </td>
        <td style="display: none;">
          No
        </td>
        <td>
          sfdf ,sdffssd,sdfhshdj,
        </td>
        <td>
          Acsadfds
        </td>
        <td>
          06/30/2016
        </td>
        <td>
          0
        </td>
        <td>
          sfasd
        </td>
        <td>
          06/30/2016
        </td>
        <td>
          sdasd
        </td>
        <td>
          <a target="_blank" class="linkth">Preview&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          579850
        </td>
        <td>
          sdfff sdfabsd sjd </td>
        <td>
          US asdfd
        </td>
        <td>
          sdfsdsdsd
        </td>
        <td>
          sdfsfdfas
        </td>
        <td style="display: none;">
          No
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf,
        </td>
        <td>
          sdfsdsda
        </td>
        <td>
          06/30/2016
        </td>
        <td>
          0
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf
        </td>
        <td>
          07/04/2016
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf
        </td>
        <td>
          <a target="_blank" class="linkth">Preview&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          579893
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf sdfha sdfsfh
        </td>
        <td>
          US sdfsdfgl
        </td>
        <td>
          dfsjsdsd
        </td>
        <td>
          sdfdfjk
        </td>
        <td style="display: none;">
          No
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf
        </td>
        <td>
          sdfgagf
        </td>
        <td>
          06/30/2016
        </td>
        <td>
          0
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf
        </td>
        <td>
          06/28/2016
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf
        </td>
        <td>
          <a target="_blank" class="linkth">Preview&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          545554
        </td>
        <td>
          jhsdfg sdfhh sdafjh
        </td>
        <td>
          US sdfhhdf
        </td>
        <td>
          sdfadilgf
        </td>
        <td>
          tadil
        </td>
        <td style="display: none;">
          No
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf
        </td>
        <td>
          tadil
        </td>
        <td>
          08/08/2003
        </td>
        <td>
          0
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf
        </td>
        <td>
          06/29/2016
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf
        </td>
        <td>
          <a target="_blank" class="linkth">Preview&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          579892
        </td>
        <td>
          sadfs asdfhds dbsh dfsdh
        </td>
        <td>
          US tadil
        </td>
        <td>
          sddftadil
        </td>
        <td>
          fftadil
        </td>
        <td style="display: none;">
          No
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf
        </td>
        <td>
          Active
        </td>
        <td>
          06/30/2016
        </td>
        <td>
          0
        </td>
        <td>
          tadil fsddf
        </td>
        <td>
          06/29/2016
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf
        </td>
        <td>
          <a target="_blank" class="linkth">Preview&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          579855
        </td>
        <td>
          jsdhfsdfb dfs bsdhfdjs bsdhbh
        </td>
        <td>
          US tadil
        </td>
        <td>
          sdftadil
        </td>
        <td>
          fjtadil
        </td>
        <td style="display: none;">
          No
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf
        </td>
        <td>
          tadil
        </td>
        <td>
          06/30/2016
        </td>
        <td>
          0
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          06/21/2016
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a target="_blank" class="linkth">Preview&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          579851
        </td>
        <td>
          asdhshj- jd dsjsh jjsd
        </td>
        <td>
          US tadil
        </td>
        <td>
          tadil
        </td>
        <td>
          Retail
        </td>
        <td style="display: none;">
          No
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf
        </td>
        <td>
          tadil
        </td>
        <td>
          06/30/2016
        </td>
        <td>
          0
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf
        </td>
        <td>
          06/29/2016
        </td>
        <td>
          sdhafasdjfj sdhfasdsf
        </td>
        <td>

          <a target="_blank" class="linkth">Preview&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>



        <td>
          579842
        </td>
        <td>

          Test sdhfhad bsdbh
        </td>


        <td>
          US English
        </td>
        <td>
          Internal
        </td>
        <td>
          tadil
        </td>
        <td style="display: none;">
          No
        </td>


        <td>
          sdfffa ,dsjfjs,
        </td>
        <td>
          Active
        </td>
        <td>
          06/30/2016
        </td>


        <td>
          0
        </td>
        <td>
          sdafsfsd
        </td>
        <td>
          07/01/2016
        </td>
        <td>
          asdff
        </td>
        <td>

          <a target="_blank" class="linkth">Preview&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zwdg1nu/)</kbd>

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmqjnjc8/)</kbd> by using the provided link of the original question.

Just look at the above fiddle, when there are more headers,table gets distorted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrollable table with fixed header in bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap)