# Align the thead and tbody elements with ability of fixing the thead and making tbody scrollable

Tags: css

I have applied following CSS to my table.

```
thead, tbody 
{ 
   display: block; 
}

tbody 
{
    height: 200px;        
    overflow-y: auto;  
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

The objective is to make the `thead` fixed, and keep `tbody` scrolling. Before applying the above CSS, `thead` and `tbody` content was alligned properly. But after putting the CSS, the content is mis-aligned. Even `tr` elements doesn't fill the entire space of their container. Can someone help me with this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please share what you have tried with snippet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table fixed header and scrollable body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/table-fixed-header-and-scrollable-body)

Comment: You better used a wrapper and position:sticky to avoid to break the table layout algoritme

Answer (score 0):

try this code for sticky header and scrollable body for table. hope will work for you.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
th{
  position: sticky;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      top: -1px;
      z-index: 999;
      background-color: #000;
      color:white;
  
}
.sticky-table {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky-table">
      <table>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
          <th>m-1</th>
        <th>m-2</th>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>user 1</td>
              <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>     
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>user 2</td>
               <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>     
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>user 3</td>
              <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>user 4</td>
          <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>user 5</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
               <td>67</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: It helped. But in my table, in every row, there is one checkbox also in the starting column, so when i am scrolling, the checkbox is showing in header also, with white color..It's not looking good. Is there any way to make the checkbox black as soon as it goes to thead.