# How can I prevent this table row from appearing behind my table header?

Tags: html, css

My goal is to apply sticky headers to a table using a pure CSS approach.

Using this as a guide.  [Table fixed header and scrollable body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/table-fixed-header-and-scrollable-body)

When the page renders the table looks fine, when I start scrolling you can see a sliver of the  data above the table header.

[image: Once you start scrolling you can see the text appearing above the <th>]

```
 <div class="large-12 columns" ng-show="$ctrl.filteredParticipantsDt.length != 0">
    <div style="max-height: 260px; overflow: auto;" class="tableFixHead">
        <table border="1" style="width: 100%" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th><a ng-click="$ctrl.orderByField='ID_NBR'; $ctrl.reverseSort = !$ctrl.reverseSort" refresh-session>IDENTIFIER
                    <span ng-show="$ctrl.orderByField == 'ID_NBR'"><span ng-show="!$ctrl.reverseSort" class="fi-arrow-up"></span><span ng-show="$ctrl.reverseSort" class="fi-arrow-down"></span></span></a></th>
                <th><a ng-click="$ctrl.orderByField='CNCAT_LST_FRST_M_I'; $ctrl.reverseSort = !$ctrl.reverseSort" refresh-session>PERSON
                    <span ng-show="$ctrl.orderByField == 'CNCAT_LST_FRST_M_I'"><span ng-show="!$ctrl.reverseSort" class="fi-arrow-up"></span><span ng-show="$ctrl.reverseSort" class="fi-arrow-down"></span></span></a></th>
                <th><a ng-click="$ctrl.orderByField='SHRT_DESC'; $ctrl.reverseSort = !$ctrl.reverseSort" refresh-session>ROLE
                    <span ng-show="$ctrl.orderByField == 'SHRT_DESC'"><span ng-show="!$ctrl.reverseSort" class="fi-arrow-up"></span><span ng-show="$ctrl.reverseSort" class="fi-arrow-down"></span></span></a></th>
                <th><a ng-click="$ctrl.orderByField='EFF_DT'; $ctrl.reverseSort = !$ctrl.reverseSort" refresh-session>EFFECTIVE DATE
                    <span ng-show="$ctrl.orderByField == 'EFF_DT'"><span ng-show="!$ctrl.reverseSort" class="fi-arrow-up"></span><span ng-show="$ctrl.reverseSort" class="fi-arrow-down"></span></span></a></th>
                <th><a ng-click="$ctrl.orderByField='END_DT'; $ctrl.reverseSort = !$ctrl.reverseSort" refresh-session>END DATE
                    <span ng-show="$ctrl.orderByField == 'END_DT'"><span ng-show="!$ctrl.reverseSort" class="fi-arrow-up"></span><span ng-show="$ctrl.reverseSort" class="fi-arrow-down"></span></span></a></th>
                </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                
        <tr ng-repeat="a in $ctrl.filteredParticipantsDt|orderBy:$ctrl.orderByField:!$ctrl.reverseSort" 
            ng-click="$ctrl.setSelected(a)" 
            ng-class="{Highlight: a.PCR_ID === $ctrl.Selected.PCR_ID, endDatedRow: a.END_DATED_IND == 'Y'}" refresh-session>
                <td>{{a.ID_NBR}}</td>
                <td>{{ a.CNCAT_LST_FRST_M_I }}</td>
                <td>{{a.SHRT_DESC}}</td>
                <td>{{a.DISPLAYEFF}}</td>
                <td>{{a.DISPLAYEND || ''}}</td>
                </tr>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe it will be better for everyone that you provide a real example using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know its a bit late to answer, but I had this exact issue. The problem is the table header has an invisible border that needs to be removed in order to not see that extra pixel behind it. The inline solution for brevity sake:

```
<div class="large-12 columns" ng-show="$ctrl.filteredParticipantsDt.length != 0">
<div style="max-height: 260px; overflow: auto;" class="tableFixHead">
    <table border="1" style="width: 100%" >
        <thead>
            <tr(style="border-style:hidden")>
. . .
```

Comment: Thx Davileet, i'll check it out and update as the answer if it works.