# HTML input inside table cell

Tags: html, css

I have a table that will contain many columns and I would like to add `input` fields inside header cells, but I would like for the input to fit the width depending on the body content.

This is how it looks like without the `input` fields:
[image]

And this is how it looks like with the `input` fields:

As it can be seen, columns like 'index' and 'Is Active' are taking too much space, and I would like to maintain the first layout as much as possible. I tried to set input width to 100% and auto, but it doesn't seem to help very much.

The current css looks like:

```css
.table {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.table thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.table thead th {
  border: 1px solid #e4eff8;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table thead th.header-label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #e4eff8, #4578a2 5%, #e4eff8 150%);
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.table td {
  border: 1px solid #e4eff8;
}

.table input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header-label">Index</th>
      <th class="header-label">Name</th>
      <th class="header-label">Phone</th>
      <th class="header-label">Company</th>
      <th class="header-label">Registered</th>
      <th class="header-label">Is Active</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="number"></th>
      <th><input type="string"></th>
      <th><input type="string"></th>
      <th><input type="string"></th>
      <th><input type="date"></th>
      <th><input type="boolean"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Paige Bean</td>
      <td>+1 (871) 458-2959</td>
      <td>MOREGANIC</td>
      <td>2018-12-27T11:28:50 -01:00</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Knox Holman</td>
      <td>+1 (880) 497-2808</td>
      <td>MAINELAND</td>
      <td>2017-05-07T02:54:22 -01:00</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Brandy Colon</td>
      <td>+1 (969) 513-2827</td>
      <td>NEXGENE</td>
      <td>2017-06-07T06:42:31 -00:00</td>
      <td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Suzette Austin</td>
      <td>+1 (863) 445-3604</td>
      <td>JETSILK</td>
      <td>2015-10-24T11:10:41 -01:00</td>
      <td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Downs Cain</td>
      <td>+1 (822) 574-2617</td>
      <td>INSECTUS</td>
      <td>2017-10-19T08:18:09 -01:00</td>
      <td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Michael Yang</td>
      <td>+1 (875) 492-3905</td>
      <td>DELPHIDE</td>
      <td>2016-08-15T01:31:55 -01:00</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So how do you make this happen with pure css, without hard coding the width of each column?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a short HTML snippet

Comment: i think a `width auto` with proper parent styling will work, but a snippet to play with the code would be great.

Comment: I made you a snippet Please update with relevant HTML

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: I added an short html snippet

Comment: i am not sure if it is possible with css only, but you could do it with js

Comment: @Ayoub.A Yes, I've seen it. Thanks for adding, you spared me some time of creating it myself  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the text on the input can't be predicted, every input with width:100% tries to get the most width it can. The **solution** is use a wrapping `div` with `absolute positioning`.

This is how it works (it obvious to me that OP understands the "wrapper div with absolute position" trick. The following is intended for someone learning CSS):

- `.table .tr-inputs th` has `position: relative` so it serves as reference for child absolute positioned objects. We do not set anything about width (so it's completely auto), and we set a `padding-bottom: 1.2rem` to keep the `th` with the correct height for our absolute positioned elements (since absolute positioned elements are removed from the flow and "does not take any space").
- `.table .tr-inputs div` is our wrapper div. We set `position: absolute` and set all `top`,`right`,`left`,`bottom` to `0`. Then, it stretches it self to fill its `relative positioned` parent, which is our `.table .tr-inputs th`.
- `input` has `width: 100%` so it takes all the width of its parent, which is our `absolute positioned` wrapper div.

```css
.table {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.table thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.table thead th {
  border: 1px solid #e4eff8;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table thead th.header-label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #e4eff8, #4578a2 5%, #e4eff8 150%);
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.table td {
  border: 1px solid #e4eff8;
}

.table .tr-inputs th {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1.2rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.table .tr-inputs div {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.table input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header-label">Index</th>
      <th class="header-label">Name</th>
      <th class="header-label">Phone</th>
      <th class="header-label">Company</th>
      <th class="header-label">Registered</th>
      <th class="header-label">Is Active</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-inputs">
      <th>
        <div><input type="number"></div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div><input type="string"></div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div><input type="string"></div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div><input type="string"></div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div><input type="date"></div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div><input type="boolean"></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Paige Bean</td>
      <td>+1 (871) 458-2959</td>
      <td>MOREGANIC</td>
      <td>2018-12-27T11:28:50 -01:00</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Knox Holman</td>
      <td>+1 (880) 497-2808</td>
      <td>MAINELAND</td>
      <td>2017-05-07T02:54:22 -01:00</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Brandy Colon</td>
      <td>+1 (969) 513-2827</td>
      <td>NEXGENE</td>
      <td>2017-06-07T06:42:31 -00:00</td>
      <td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Suzette Austin</td>
      <td>+1 (863) 445-3604</td>
      <td>JETSILK</td>
      <td>2015-10-24T11:10:41 -01:00</td>
      <td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Downs Cain</td>
      <td>+1 (822) 574-2617</td>
      <td>INSECTUS</td>
      <td>2017-10-19T08:18:09 -01:00</td>
      <td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Michael Yang</td>
      <td>+1 (875) 492-3905</td>
      <td>DELPHIDE</td>
      <td>2016-08-15T01:31:55 -01:00</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think we should use `display: block;` instead of `inline-block` for `.table .tr-inputs div `

Comment: @Gilboot Sometimes the backend platform can insert/passthrough undesirable characters, like newline, which could lead to gaps on the layout. With `inline-block`, even if these characters are present, there won't be gaps.

Answer (score 3):

- Never `position: sticky` `<thead>` elements. Use [This solution instead: **Table fixed header and scrollable body**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47923622/383904)
- Use `background-color` on `<th>` elements
- Don't use padding on `<th>` elements  - Use it on an inner `.header-label` `<div>`
- `.header-label` should be an inner DIV if you want, no need to *"classify"* `<th>` elements
- `type="boolean"` is an invalid *`type`* value. Use `string` or rather a `type="checkbox"`

```css
/*QuickReset*/*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}

/*
tableFixHead  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47923622/383904
*/

.tableFixHead {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 180px;
}

.tableFixHead thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.table th {
  background: #fff;
}

.table th .header-label {
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #e4eff8, #4578a2 5%, #e4eff8 150%);
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.table td {
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e4eff8;
}

.table input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font: 14px/1.4 sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><div class="header-label">Index</div><input type="number"></th>
        <th><div class="header-label">Name</div><input type="string"></th>
        <th><div class="header-label">Phone</div><input type="string"></th>
        <th><div class="header-label">Company</div><input type="string"></th>
        <th><div class="header-label">Registered</div><input type="date"></th>
        <th><div class="header-label">Is Active</div><input type="string"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>Paige Bean</td>
        <td>+1 (871) 458-2959</td>
        <td>MOREGANIC</td>
        <td>2018-12-27T11:28:50 -01:00</td>
        <td>false</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Knox Holman</td>
        <td>+1 (880) 497-2808</td>
        <td>MAINELAND</td>
        <td>2017-05-07T02:54:22 -01:00</td>
        <td>false</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Brandy Colon</td>
        <td>+1 (969) 513-2827</td>
        <td>NEXGENE</td>
        <td>2017-06-07T06:42:31 -00:00</td>
        <td>true</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Suzette Austin</td>
        <td>+1 (863) 445-3604</td>
        <td>JETSILK</td>
        <td>2015-10-24T11:10:41 -01:00</td>
        <td>true</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Downs Cain</td>
        <td>+1 (822) 574-2617</td>
        <td>INSECTUS</td>
        <td>2017-10-19T08:18:09 -01:00</td>
        <td>true</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Michael Yang</td>
        <td>+1 (875) 492-3905</td>
        <td>DELPHIDE</td>
        <td>2016-08-15T01:31:55 -01:00</td>
        <td>false</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
.table th {
    padding : 0;
    padding-right :  0.2rem;
}

.table td {
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Instead of :

```
.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could use absolute position inputs and relative position wrapper around it to match the column size.

I dont think it is a good solution but it works.

As mentioned in the answer from @Roko C. Buljan there are some points you could do better.

```css
.table {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.table thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.table thead th {
  border: 1px solid #e4eff8;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table thead th.header-label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #e4eff8, #4578a2 5%, #e4eff8 150%);
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: realtive;
}

.table td {
  border: 1px solid #e4eff8;
}

.table .input_wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.table .input_wrapper::after{
  content: "+";
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
}

.table input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header-label">Index</th>
      <th class="header-label">Name</th>
      <th class="header-label">Phone</th>
      <th class="header-label">Company</th>
      <th class="header-label">Registered</th>
      <th class="header-label">Is Active</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="input_wrapper"><input type="number"></div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="input_wrapper"><input type=" string"></div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="input_wrapper"><input type="string"></div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="input_wrapper"><input type="string"></div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="input_wrapper"><input type="date"></div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="input_wrapper"><input type="boolean"></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Paige Bean</td>
      <td>+1 (871) 458-2959</td>
      <td>MOREGANIC</td>
      <td>2018-12-27T11:28:50 -01:00</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Knox Holman</td>
      <td>+1 (880) 497-2808</td>
      <td>MAINELAND</td>
      <td>2017-05-07T02:54:22 -01:00</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Brandy Colon</td>
      <td>+1 (969) 513-2827</td>
      <td>NEXGENE</td>
      <td>2017-06-07T06:42:31 -00:00</td>
      <td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Suzette Austin</td>
      <td>+1 (863) 445-3604</td>
      <td>JETSILK</td>
      <td>2015-10-24T11:10:41 -01:00</td>
      <td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Downs Cain</td>
      <td>+1 (822) 574-2617</td>
      <td>INSECTUS</td>
      <td>2017-10-19T08:18:09 -01:00</td>
      <td>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Michael Yang</td>
      <td>+1 (875) 492-3905</td>
      <td>DELPHIDE</td>
      <td>2016-08-15T01:31:55 -01:00</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple javascript solution if you want:

change this section of HTML:

```
<tr>
  <th><div class="input-container"><input type="number"></div></th>
  <th><div class="input-container"><input type="string"></div></th>
  <th><div class="input-container"><input type="string"></div></th>
  <th><div class="input-container"><input type="string"></div></th>
  <th><div class="input-container"><input type="date"></div></th>
  <th><div class="input-container"><input type="boolean"></div></th>
</tr>
```

add this to your CSS:

```
table .input-container {
  width: 0;
}
```

and link this javascript to your HTML:

```
let cont = document.querySelectorAll('.input-container')
for (let i = 0; i < cont.length; i++) {
  cont[i].style.width = cont[i].parentNode.offsetWidth + 'px'
}
```