# How can i make my td and th have the same width - including the scroll bar putted on the tbody only?

Tags: html, css

I need to have scrollable tbody. For that reason i putted two tables one for thead and for one tbody.

But i can't find a way to make this two tables have same width.

I know that there are a lot of solutions out there for making these with one table but none of them is working fine - because i need to have thead with bakground - color - the other solutions have width until the scroll bar on the right and that is not what i want

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="red">
                Header 1
            </th>

            <th class="red">
                Header 2
            </th>

            <th class="red">
                Header 3
            </th>
            <th class="red">
                Header 4
            </th>

            <th class="red">
                Header 5
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="red">Content 1</td>
            <td class="red">Content 2</td>
            <td class="red">Content 3</td>
            <td class="red">Content 4</td>
            <td class="red">Content 5</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="red">Content 1</td>
            <td class="red">Content 2</td>
            <td class="red">Content 3</td>
            <td class="red">Content 4</td>
            <td class="red">Content 5</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="red">Content 1</td>
            <td class="red">Content 2</td>
            <td class="red">Content 3</td>
            <td class="red">Content 4</td>
            <td class="red">Content 5</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="red">Content 1</td>
            <td class="red">Content 2</td>
            <td class="red">Content 3</td>
            <td class="red">Content 4</td>
            <td class="red">Content 5</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td class="red">Content 1</td>
            <td class="red">Content 2</td>
            <td class="red">Content 3</td>
            <td class="red">Content 4</td>
            <td class="red">Content 5</td>
        </tr>
       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

table {
    border:1px solid red;
}

.red {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: so you want to create same width column in 2 table? how about add style in thead with display: block

Answer (score 0):

[Table fixed header and scrollable body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/table-fixed-header-and-scrollable-body)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-table-with-fixed-header-and-scrollable-body/

try one of these

PLease make it one table not two

Comment: As i said the solutions you provided are with scrollbar on whole table - not only the tbody as i need

Comment: No, check the links both links is giving examples of a fixed header and scrollable body

Comment: You don't understand. Scrollable tbody starts from the body itself, not from the top from the table

Comment: On the lunks you priovided - on the right from the table headers there is scrollbar, i don't need that scrollabr right from the table headers - i need him just from the tbody