# Scrollable html-table scrolls by sticky header

Tags: html, css, html-table, sticky

When creating a scrollable table with HTML and CSS the body of the table scrolls behind the sticky table-header and is at least in part visible above the header.

There are many similar questions already around. The one that helped me the most was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/table-fixed-header-and-scrollable-body?newreg=5350ef32c112494cb6c3384554a04a4e). If I had enough karma as of the time of writing this, I'd just comment my solution in that specific question. Seeing how often this problem occurs and is asked for, I decided to contribute my little titbit of information this way.

Up until now I couldn't find the solution to my specific problem though. At least for my use case, when the table isn't the only thing on the site, the table body kept scrolling past / behind the header and was visible above the header, which looked rather bad.

Given is the following table, which resulted in the above described behavior  (original code by Roko C. Buljan in above linked question):

```css
.tableFixHead          { overflow: auto; height: 100px; }
.tableFixHead thead th { position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 1; }

/* Just common table stuff. Really. */
table  { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
th, td { padding: 8px 16px; }
th     { background:#eee; }
```

```html
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>TH 1</th><th>TH 2</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>E1</td><td>E2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you meant to ask a question and then to answer it. You should have a separate question and answer.

Comment: @RuanMendes you're right, that is the more sensible way to do it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Above code snippet might already work totally fine for you but if you happen to have the same problem as me, you want to change it ever so slightly. In `.tableFixHead` you want to add `padding-top: o;`.

```css
.tableFixHead          { overflow: auto; height: 100px; padding-top: 0; }
.tableFixHead thead th { position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 1; }

/* Just common table stuff. Really. */
table  { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
th, td { padding: 8px 16px; }
th     { background:#eee; }
```

```html
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>TH 1</th><th>TH 2</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>E1</td><td>E2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Running this code here on stackoverflow will likely show no difference. But depending on the position of your table and it's interaction with other objects this might be the solution you've been looking for.

This way the table will begin with your header and not a little bit (=the padding) above it.

Depending on your underlying CSS `border-top` or `margin-top` might be your solution. I'm happy to be corrected on this, if it can't be either of them.